# How to include sizzle.js with jquery so it works when offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

I have a javascript datetime picker that uses jquery with sizzle.js. It only works when connected to the internet. 
I have tried to include sizzle.js separately:

```
    <script src="/vsg/inc/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/vsg/inc/js/sizzle.js"></script>
```

I have looked around and can't seem to find an answer.

```
    *!
     * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.1
     * http://jquery.com/
     *
     * Copyright 2011, John Resig
     * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
     * http://jquery.org/license
     *
     * Includes Sizzle.js
     * http://sizzlejs.com/
     * Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation
     * Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
     *
     * Date: Wed Feb 23 13:55:29 2011 -0500
    */
```

Comment: datepicker is part of jquery.ui

Comment: sorry yes, don't know why iv crossed my wires somewhere what I mean is the datepicker only works when connected to the internet?

Comment: open developer toolbar, go to network tab and check witch file there is problem. jQuery 1.5.1 already includes sizzle engine – there is no needed to include it one more time.